# ERROR : how to get information to foreign key laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I cannot retrieve the username from the foreign key, please help me.
The user table contains a name field I think with the foreign key I could retrieve that. But it does not work.

My migration table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('bookings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->integer('doctor_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('campagne_id');
        $table->string('time');
        $table->integer('status')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('campagne_id')->references('id')->on('campagne')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

My booking Model

```
public function utilisateur()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
public function Campagne()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Campagne::class, 'campagne_id', 'id');
}
```

}

my controller

```
public function liste()
{
    $bookings = DB::table('bookings')->paginate(6);
    return view('listeAppointement', compact('bookings', 'doctors'));
}
```

My erreur [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p0PQ.png)
i dont know happen. Thanks for advance.

Comment: can you show your controller code

Comment: I just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup is good to go, Did you verified that all reference 'user_id' from table bookings exist on users table? It happens sometimes when relation not find required field with foreign key.

Comment: I did not quite understand what you are trying to say there!

Comment: so how to do that because i did not understand your saying.

Comment: Did you verified that all 'user_id' from 'bookings' table have related user in 'users' table with matching 'id'?

Comment: To use relations, its best to use Laravel model. so your syntax $bookings = DB::table('bookings')->paginate(6); will have to be replaced with $bookings = Booking::with('utilisateur')->paginate(6); with eager loading